# I'm trying to replace/change colors in an image

Tags: gimp, color-conversion, paint.net

I have this logo that came along with a theme:

[image: Original Logo]

On a website, a new branding occurred, and now we have a limited range of colors:

```
--color-primary-blue:        rgb (44,  45,  101);
--color-primary-midblue:     rgb (104, 110, 159);
--color-primary-midbluetint: rgba(104, 110, 159, 0.70);
--color-secondary-yellow:    rgb (254, 209, 0);
```

And I attempted:

[image: Attempt 1]

and

[image: Attempt 2]

The issue is the shaded part.

It looks like this:

[image: My attempts to re-color]

**Question:** How do I change the original logo's two colors to the new ones? I need to generate both new logos. I do not own Photoshop. I only have GIMP and Paint.Net.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Do you have a layered file?  If not, it's possibly going to be easier to just recreate it in software which supports layers, such as GIMP. Then you can apply the alpha lock and fill each layer with any colour you want.

Comment: I'm afraid I have the PNG only. There are no layers.

Comment: Well in that case, just recreate it in GIMP. It's not exactly a complex design.  [Here's a very rough example](https://imgur.com/X6flBhh), just four layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's exactly wanted.The blue version probably should have this blue

[image]

But its visual brightness should follow all light and shadow variations in your original green version.

Let GIMP make it with its layer blending math:

[image]

Your original green version is pasted to a new layer above the blue and has got blending mode LCh Luminosity. The subjective brightness is taken from the original, but other aspects of the blue color stay.

The colorfulness of the light area may look too low. That's caused by the limitations of the whole RGB system. Darkening gives more room for colorfulness. Apply Color > Curves to the top layer.

The next curve is a pure guess. Try what's good for you. Before doing it make a spare duplicate of the original top layer and close it! This is the place where other programs which have adjustment layers shine (Photoshop, Krita, Affinity Photo). In GIMP one must keep spare copies of the layers because adjustments cannot be taken back nor tuned later.

[image]

The result will be different if the same curve is applied to a flattened single layer image.

To get the yellow areas you must add a new top layer and make selections which are filled with yellow. It's best to try the curves-trick to the original after inserting the new layer with yellow areas, because which looks right depend on the whole image. One result:

[image]

The shadows are darkened more with steeper curve than in the previous example.

As said by others, you should redraw the whole image. It's especially important if you have only a low resolution PNG version. The jagginess of the low resolution image is easy to see when there's high contrasts like the border of the yellow.

Redraw it in Inkscape. This is a perfect starters project. There you get a version which is sharp in all sizes and can be also exported as PNG. In Inkscape the shadow can be a blurred black or dark blue version of the shape which is made partially transparent.